# Is there a black list of applications that drain battery fast?

Tags: battery, battery-life

Many people complain about some applications draining batteries fast because of bugs or misconfiguration. Is there a black list of such applications that are not energy-friendly?

Comment: I've not seen such a list, but you can easily see on your own device the apps and processes that are draining your battery.

Comment: NB: if such a list exists, this question is a good place to link to it. If such a list does not exist, this question is NOT a good place to create it. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky to know which ones drain battery life fast.
Before installing you can check comments to see if there are many complaining of that.
After installing, either if you know your phone well enough and see a clear decrease in battery life then it could be the new software if nothing else change, or you can try and check the battery usage statistics.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this App [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5vYXNpc2ZlbmcuZ3JlZW5pZnkiXQ..) , If you got rooted phone that is.

Anyway for general purpose you should check battery usage to find the culprit. And Have them removed perhaps.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5vYXNpc2ZlbmcuZ3JlZW5pZnkiXQ..